# reduce() hstack python

Tags: python, reduce, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use *reduce()* function to create a function *hstack()* which horizontally stacks multiple arrays. As a simple example, lets say

```
>>>>M=eye((4))
>>>>M
    array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

>>>>hstack([M,M])
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

This works as I want. Now I define

```
>>>> hstackm = lambda *args: reduce(hstack, args)
```

And try to do the *hstack()* from the previous case

```
>>>>hstackm([M,M])  
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]),
 array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])]
```

Which is incorrect. How do I define *hstackm()* to obtain a proper output?

My final objective will be to create a *hstackm()* function to stack SPARSE matrices if it is possible. Something like,

```
hstackm = lambda *args: reduce(sparse.hstack, args).
```

The _*args_ would be *csr* or _lil_matrix_

thank you

Comment: Don't use reduce. Don't use lambda if you're going to name the function. Is is much difficult to write a `for` loop?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? By the sound of it `numpy.hstack` does *exactly* what you want.

Comment: thank you @JBernardo, you are right the for loop it is simpler, but I want to use it several times, and after defining once the hstackm, it will save me some time.

Comment: @manolius define it with the proper `def` statement with a for loop. It'll be readable after 10 years unlike that "reduce with lambda" line.

Comment: @JBernardo, that was interesting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [16]: hstackm = lambda args: reduce(lambda x,y:hstack((x,y)), args)

In [17]: hstackm([M,M])
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `hstack` takes *one* parameter, a list of matrices. `reduce()` calls it with *two parameters* instead, each a matrix.

Change your `hstack` method to accept an arbitrary number of arguments instead:

```
def hstack(*matrices):
    ....
```

instead of `hstack(matrices)`, then call it as `hstack(M, M)`.